# Publish Facebook Workplace's custom integration

Tags: facebook-workplace

Is it possible to publish a Facebook Workplace's custom integration for other Workgroup users? If yes, then how?

Workplace: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace

Comment: Can you elaborate on what specifically it is that you're trying to do?

Comment: @brad, I created a custom integration (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/integrations/custom-integrations) and want to publish it to other workgroup's teams. Is it possible?

Comment: You mean you want to allow other companies to use your integration?  Or other groups/teams within your own company?

Comment: Custom integration is available to all members within a company who created it. I wonder how to make it available for other companies as well.

Comment: Is it possible to make it available for other companies? Thanks

Comment: How to publish a post ( an image or text ) from app to workplace page?